# How to debug a rails app in docker with pry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, pry

I have a rails app running in a docker container in development environment.

When I try to debug it with placing `binding.pry` somewhere in the code and attaching to the container I can see the `pry` prompt in the output but it doesn't pause on it and I can't interact with it like it was without docker container.

So how do I debug a containerized app?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you're using docker-compose, you can add these flags to `docker-compose.yml`:

```
app:
  tty: true
  stdin_open: true
```

And then attach to your process with `docker attach project_app_1`. `pry-rails` works here now. Ensure `less` is installed on your container for the optimal pry experience.

cf. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/423#issuecomment-141995398

Comment: Any idea how to run this in a local k8s deployment? I'm running minikube and deploying with skaffold.

Answer (score 37):

to use pry you have to run it differently:

`docker-compose run --service-ports web`

check out this article for more info:

http://blog.carbonfive.com/2015/03/17/docker-rails-docker-compose-together-in-your-development-workflow/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This solution was not adequate for me because other of my services depend on being linked to the right instance of this service I want to debug.

Comment: what is --service-ports for?

Comment: For me this is working solution. Adding `stdin_open`, `tty` to docker-compose file have issue - for some reason new logs not printed to terminal if service was inactive for a minute or so (there are multiple issues on `docker-compose` and `moby` repos), this command allowing to debug and keep our logs stream alive.

Answer (score 22):

as **Gabe Kopley** answer, assume your rails container is called `app`, set `stdin_open` and `tty` to `true`:

```
app:
  stdin_open: true
  tty: true
```

and I wrote a bash script to make life easier, save it to `bin/dev`:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker-compose up -d && docker attach $(docker-compose ps -q app)
```

don't forget to make `dev` be executable by `chmod +x bin/dev`

In your terminal, type `bin/dev`, it will automatically run up containers and attach the app container. when `binding.pry` called, you can type to the terminal directly.

Comment: Attach command gives me '"docker attach" requires exactly 1 argument.' when I'm running `docker-compose run app rails c` in parallel with server.
You may use `docker attach $(docker-compose ps | grep app_1 | awk '{print $1}')` to fix it

Comment: thanks that worked fine. I wonder though, how can I interact with the terminal? My text doesn't get printed when I type instantly untill I send the command

Answer (score 8):

I had this same issue when I was running pry in Passenger. Try changing `"pry-rails"` in the Gemfile to `gem "pry-remote"`, which will initiate a dRuby, or distributed protocol with no dependencies.

Where you want to stop the code in execution call `"binding.remote_pry"` as opposed to `"binding.pry"`

Then just call `remote-pry` in the console to access it. It should work the same. In your test environment just the usual `binding.pry` works fine.

Comment: For anyone building CircleCI config.yml files, using Docker locally (ie: Docker Desktop), using the "circleci local execute', and wants to debug Ruby code, the gem pry-remote is a lifesaver! I am able to spin up my CircleCI jobs, stop at breakpoints in the containers, and use standard pry commands. A real gem!!

Answer (score 5):

If you don't use `docker-compose` though, you can simply run the container with `-it` option.

For example:

```
docker run -v /Users/adam/Documents/Rails/Blog/:/usr/src/app -p 3000:3000 -it blog
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are running in under alpine linux aka `ruby-*-alpine` you need to install package ncurses wich includes `infocmp`.

If that's the reason you will have this in your error log:

```
bin/rails: No such file or directory - infocmp                                                              
Error: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass 
...
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'                                                                                                                 
FATAL: Pry failed to get user input using `Readline`.                                                       
To fix this you may be able to pass input and output file descriptors to pry directly. e.g.                                    
  Pry.config.input = STDIN                                                                                   
  Pry.config.output = STDOUT                                                                           
  binding.pry
```

To fix it, on your `Dockerfile` add:

```
RUN apk add ncurses
```

Although You probably already had an `apk add` line, so just add `ncurses` there.

then you can do