# How to debug a rails app in docker with pry and foreman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, foreman

Developing a ruby on rails app with foreman, docker, pry.

Checked this article already.
[How to debug a rails app in docker with pry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35211638/how-to-debug-a-rails-app-in-docker-with-pry)

I usually use `docker-compose run --service-ports web` to debug with `binding.pry.`

But with foreman, `docker-compose run --service-ports web` does not work.

`docker attach` works, but its not useful as `docker-compose run --service-ports web`

Any solution to make it work like `docker-compose run --service-ports web` with foreman?

Answer (score 0):

Foreman seems to be the culprit. I was facing a similar issue and I managed to solve it by creating new services in the docker-compose file for each service described in the Procfile.

Before:

```
web:
  build: .
  entrypoint: ./entrypoint-dev.sh
  command: bash -c "bundle exec foreman start -f Procfile.dev -p 3000"
  tty: true
  volumes:
  - .:/usr/src/app
  - bundle:/usr/local/bundle
  ports:
  - 3000:3000
environment:
  - RAILS_MAX_THREADS=5
  - RAILS_ENV=development
  - RACK_ENV=development
  - DATABASE_HOST=db
  - DATABASE_USER=postgres
  - DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
depends_on:
  - db
  - redis
```

After:

```
  js:
    build:
      context: "."
    tty: true
    command: "yarn build --watch"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app

  css:
    build:
      context: "."
    tty: true
    command: "yarn build:css --watch"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/lazy-joker

  web:
    build: .
    entrypoint: ./entrypoint-dev.sh
    command: bash -c "bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - bundle:/usr/local/bundle
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - RAILS_MAX_THREADS=5
      - RAILS_ENV=development
      - RACK_ENV=development
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_USER=postgres
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - js
      - css
```

You need to attach your terminal to the docker container in order to debug:

```
docker attach container_id
```

PS: You can get the container id by running `docker container ls`.