# Using Pry in Rails with Docker compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, pry

The pry gem was in the test group:

```
group :test do
  gem 'pry', '~> 0.12.2'
end
```

It was working.

I moved it the another group.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry', '~> 0.12.2'
end
```

If I execute rspec, the `binding.pry` works. It halts execution however if I just run `docker-compose up` to start the local dev env, and add `binding.pry` somewhere, it does not work.

I followed the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35211638/how-to-debug-a-rails-app-in-docker-with-pry) and rebuilt the container. Started the container however, `binding.pry` still doesn't work. It doesn't halt execution.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:

# Port 3010 is used for accessing running app in test mode from selenium service.
# Shm size needed for tests: https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/issues/20
  app:
    extends:
      file: common-services.yml
      service: evt_portal_app
    command: docker/wait-for-postgres.sh db docker/start-${RAILS_ENV}.sh
    shm_size: 256M
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}"
      - "3010:3010"
    links:
      - db
      - webpack_dev_server
    networks:
      - default
```

and here's my `docker-compose.develop.yml`

```
services:

# Port 3010 is used for accessing running app in test mode from selenium service.
# Shm size needed for tests: https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/issues/20
  app:
    extends:
      file: common-services.yml
      service: evt_portal_app
    command: docker/start-${RAILS_ENV}.sh
    shm_size: 128M
    ports:
      - "8083:3003"
    expose:
      - "3010"
    restart: always
    mem_limit: 4g
    memswap_limit: 4g
    depends_on:
      - delayed_job
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

Here's a picture of the attached terminal (one created using `docker attach <container ID>`):
[image]

As you can see, the execution is not halted.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running Puma? If so the pry will be stuck in a given thread and we wont be able to access it.

In `config/puma.rb` you will see that there is a variable to define the number of threads.

```
ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
```

So just make sure you set `RAILS_MAX_THREADS` to 1.

Then attach to the container and the pry should stop there:

```
docker attach <container_name>
```